Why does adding too much DIAX make bread like Soreen malt loaf?
If one adds too much Diastatic Malt to bread instead of it being spongy and springy it is sticky and when one compresses it it stays squashed.  The texture is very reminiscent of Soreen malt loaf, which I guess is no coincidence.
What is going on to cause this effect?  Is it an increase in the concentration of maltose?  It is a shortening of the starch molecules?  Presence of the enzyme?  Something else?
